# Google Maps - Get Polygon border of zones/neighborhood

Tags: google-maps

I want to make a simple search on Google Maps API v3 and get as a result the map with a colored polygon like the picture below:

Search: pinheiros, sao paulo

[image]

Answer (score 23):

I got it by using [WikiMapia](http://WikiMapia.org) data.

The steps are:

- Open [WikiMapia](http://WikiMapia.org).
- Press `F12` or `Ctrl+Shift+I`.

[image]

- Search the location that you want.
- Click with the right button on neighborhood and choose `Edit Poly`.
  [image]
- On the developer tools click in `Network` and filter by `getPolygon`.
  [image]
- Copy server response that looks like:
  [image]
- And go to `Console` tab to execute the function: `Wikimapia.Parser.Itiles.prototype.decodePolygon("Copyed text here");`
- Press enter to execute after this the Console will return the object with the points (The path of Poly).

I use `JSON.stringify` to transform the object in JSON.

Example:

```
JSON.stringify(Wikimapia.Parser.Itiles.prototype.decodePolygon("-619402099;-109032887;02fe8953fffe5a000ae5fe379a000fedffd250000e40ffd6050007f7ffeff2001925ffd59b001f6fffdc310012dcffed10003b82ffd9b9005514ffc4520053d2ffc807000c92fff82dfffde7000e670005070012ef0009390021bf000572001358fffc3a001a57fffa210013c1ffff940036530008610022fc000284004732fff5f0001fb1fff2960013c1fff80800594efffde7002c72000f16004b5000204600416f0013b2002292"))
```

The code above will return this JSON (indentation in [JsonFormatter](http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com)):

```
{
   "points":[
      {
         "lat":-10.9032887,
         "lng":-61.9402099
      },
      {
         "lat":-10.9032466,
         "lng":-61.9306183
      },
      {
         "lat":-10.8915629,
         "lng":-61.9308972
      },
      {
         "lat":-10.8903934,
         "lng":-61.9313049
      },
      {
         "lat":-10.8893188,
         "lng":-61.9316697
      },
      {
         "lat":-10.8889079,
         "lng":-61.9318736
      },
      {
         "lat":-10.8878227,
         "lng":-61.9325173
      },
      {
         "lat":-10.8869061,
         "lng":-61.933322
      },
      {
         "lat":-10.8864214,
         "lng":-61.9338048
      },
      {
         "lat":-10.8854416,
         "lng":-61.9353282
      },
      {
         "lat":-10.8839139,
         "lng":-61.9375062
      },
      {
         "lat":-10.8824811,
         "lng":-61.939652
      },
      {
         "lat":-10.8822809,
         "lng":-61.9399738
      },
      {
         "lat":-10.8826496,
         "lng":-61.9399202
      },
      {
         "lat":-10.8831343,
         "lng":-61.9400489
      },
      {
         "lat":-10.8839982,
         "lng":-61.940285
      },
      {
         "lat":-10.8844934,
         "lng":-61.9404244
      },
      {
         "lat":-10.8851677,
         "lng":-61.9403279
      },
      {
         "lat":-10.8856734,
         "lng":-61.9401777
      },
      {
         "lat":-10.8870641,
         "lng":-61.940167
      },
      {
         "lat":-10.8879597,
         "lng":-61.9403815
      },
      {
         "lat":-10.8897823,
         "lng":-61.9404459
      },
      {
         "lat":-10.8905936,
         "lng":-61.9401884
      },
      {
         "lat":-10.8910993,
         "lng":-61.9398451
      },
      {
         "lat":-10.8933855,
         "lng":-61.9396412
      },
      {
         "lat":-10.8945233,
         "lng":-61.9395876
      },
      {
         "lat":-10.8964513,
         "lng":-61.9399738
      },
      {
         "lat":-10.8981264,
         "lng":-61.9408
      },
      {
         "lat":-10.8990114,
         "lng":-61.9413042
      }
   ],
   "bounds":{
      "left":-61.9413042,
      "bottom":-10.9032887,
      "right":-61.9306183,
      "top":-10.8822809,
      "centerLatLng":null
   }
}
```

Finally I use regex like this [regexr.com/3c5m2](http://regexr.com/3c5m2) to turn JSON into WKT. I don't copy entire JSON only the objects in `"points"` array in Regex. On RegExr I copy the replaced text and paste in `POLYGON((pastehere))`.

**Important!** After apply the regex you need to repeat the first point in last point.

> **-61.956523060798645 -10.877613428213532**,-61.95640504360199 -10.877718788854143,-61.956791281700134 -10.878393096072424,-61.95735991001129 -10.87805594265392,-61.95682346820831 -10.877339490373695,**-61.956523060798645 -10.877613428213532**

Then you get something like this:

```
POLYGON((-61.956523060798645 -10.877613428213532,-61.95640504360199 -10.877718788854143,-61.956791281700134 -10.878393096072424,-61.95735991001129 -10.87805594265392,-61.95682346820831 -10.877339490373695,-61.956523060798645 -10.877613428213532))
```

That can be inserted in database that supports WKT (like MySQL).

WikiMapia has an [API](http://api.wikimapia.org) then all of this process can be automatic, but this works fine for me.

Comment: I can not seem to find how this should be done through the API .. any idea?

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is: no, the Google Maps API does not provide that functionality.

One way to implement this is to find the spatial data (polygons) that you're inerested in, load it to a database (which ideally supports spatial queries), and then to query the database via AJAX to add the feature geometry as a [KMLLayer](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?utm_source=welovemapsdevelopers&utm_campaign=stackoverflow#KmlLayer) to the map, along with the corresponding push pin.

Comment: Feature request for [Google Maps Javascript API v3](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=109)

Answer (score 0):

You may check out this working on a website at [funda.nl](http://www.funda.nl/). When you select an individual property, it also shows a Google Map in which a polygon is drawn around the neighborhood of the property selected.