# Mapping Neighborhoods with Google Maps API v3

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-geocoder

I have been tinkering with the Google Map's API and trying to figure out how to "highlight" or "border" neighborhoods, and it sounds like the functionality does not exist ([Google Maps - Get Polygon border of zones/neighborhood](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10522393/google-maps-get-polygon-border-of-zones-neighborhood)). But, when I search for neighborhoods like..

Playa Del Rey, Gilbert, AZ
Santa Monica, CA

There is a dotted border surrounding the city/neighborhood. Is it possible to reference the encompassing border, and fill it or add links to it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google Maps - Get Polygon border of zones/neighborhood](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10522393/google-maps-get-polygon-border-of-zones-neighborhood)